# When i insert a new record to the employee table,then a trigger should check whether the given emp_name already exists in the employee table

Tags: sql-server

When i insert a new record to the employee table,then a trigger should check whether the given emp_name already exists in the `employee` table and if exists then add `'_1'` to `emp_name` and then insert it into the `employee` table.

I tried before insert trigger and not getting any ideas now.

Help me.

I have 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
emp_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
manager_id INT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
role VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
pay_scale VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
sal int not null,
age INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE hobby
(
hobby_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
hobby_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE emp_hobbies
(
emp_id INT references employee(emp_id),
hobby_id INT references hobby(hobby_id),
PRIMARY KEY(emp_id,hobby_id)
);
```

and a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_dup
ON employee
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
declare @e_name varchar(100);
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.emp_name
FROM employee e, inserted i
WHERE e.emp_name= i.emp_name))
INSERT INTO employee
SELECT emp_name,manager_id,gender,role,pay,sal,age
FROM inserted
ELSE
select concat(e.emp_name+'_1')as @e_name;
INSERT INTO employee
SELECT @e_name,manager_id,gender,role,pay,sal,age
FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: what if employee rows with name `Jack` and `Jack_1` both exists and you are trying to insert a new row with name `Jack`. what should be the behaviour

Comment: i need like jack_2...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Recursive CTE like this.

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
emp_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
manager_id INT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
role VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
pay_scale VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
sal int not null,
age INT NOT NULL
);
GO
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_dup
ON employee
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

 ;WITH empcte as
    (
        SELECT i.emp_name ,CASE WHEN e.emp_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END nameappend
        FROM inserted i
        LEFT JOIN employee e
        ON e.emp_name = i.emp_name 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT i.emp_name,nameappend + 1
        FROM empcte i
        INNER JOIN employee e
        ON e.emp_name = (i.emp_name + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),nameappend))
        WHERE nameappend IS NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO employee(emp_name,manager_id,gender,role,pay_scale,sal,age)
    SELECT e.new_emp_name,i.manager_id,i.gender,i.role,i.pay_scale,i.sal,age
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Emp_name,Emp_name + ISNULL('_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),MAX(nameappend)),'') as new_emp_name
        FROM empcte e
        GROUP BY emp_name
    ) e
    ON i.Emp_name = e.Emp_name
END
GO
```

**Insert**

```
insert into employee VALUES('Jack',NULL,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jackson',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jack',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jackson',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jack',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jack_1',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jack_2',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);
insert into employee VALUES('Jack',1,'M','R','GR',340,21);


select * from employee
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72bb1/1)**

**OUTPUT**

```
| emp_id |  emp_name | manager_id | gender | role | pay_scale | sal | age |
|--------|-----------|------------|--------|------|-----------|-----|-----|
|      1 |      Jack |     (null) |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      2 |   Jackson |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      3 |    Jack_1 |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      4 | Jackson_1 |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      5 |    Jack_2 |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      6 |  Jack_1_1 |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      7 |  Jack_2_1 |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
|      8 |    Jack_3 |          1 |      M |    R |        GR | 340 |  21 |
```